# running spring mvc openshift application locally

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc, jboss, openshift

I have created an Java app on openshift platform with JBoss Application Server 7 and MySQL 5.5 using eclipse and Jboss Openshift Tools. Now I wannt to run this application on localhost but I am unable to find any option to do so.

I googled and followed some links and was able to create jboss-as-7.1.1 server but cannot figure out how to run the application using this server as there is not option to select a server in Run As window of eclipse. Do i need to modify anything in project settings?

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a server adapter for your jboss-as-7.1.1 in Eclipse? I assume you did so it looks like your project is missing the required Eclipse WTP nature. Maven project (like any OpenShift Java app) get those for free if you have [m2e-wtp](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/) installed. To me it looks like you're missing that one (and eventually possibly Eclipse [m2e](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/)) and need to install it. 
Either use the Eclipse marketplace or point Eclipse to the following update site: 
http://download.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/releases/luna/